# How do I get dates to display using my settings TIME_ZONE

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, format

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have the following set in my settings file ...

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I would like for all dates to display using the default time zone I have above.  However, when I print out fields like

```
self.created_on.ctime()
```

in which "created_on" maps to a PostGres DATETIME field, the date is printed out using a UTC timezone.  How can I get this to display using the time zone I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you can use the [django.utils.timezone.localtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime)

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

localtime(self.created_on).ctime()
```

Comment: Syntax is actually localtime(self.created_on).ctime() but this does it.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

TIME_ZONE is a session parameter. Find out more [here](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime) 
and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#overview)

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
self.created_on.astimezone(timezone('America/Chicago'))
```